# Returning to parent directory with the SD library

Tags: sd-card, sd, sd.h

I have a `File` variable called `dir` and i'm building a simple file explorer for my device. Is there a way to get a reference to `dir`'s parent directory?

Comment: Doesn't dir.name() return dir's name with the path?

Comment: Unfortunately it only returns the name

Comment: Then probably the only way is to keep a list of the directories you traversed while going to that file, or while building the directory structure from root. There may be an other way, but I don't know the SD library well enough.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an inbuilt function returning the parent, but you could do:

```
FS &file_system = SD; // pick whichever file system you use

File get_parent(File dir) {
  String dirPath = dir.path();
  int lastSlashIndex = dirPath.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (lastSlashIndex != -1) {
    String parentDirPath = dirPath.substring(0, lastSlashIndex);
    File parentDir = file_system.open(parentDirPath.c_str());
    return parentDir;
  }
  return File();
}
```

Comment: but there is no `path` function in the Arduino SD library. (and no FS type)

Comment: I only have esp32-S3 at hand here, and path() is available in framework-arduinoespressif32 -> FS.h, I don't know the situation for other platforms/architectures.